# Describe an Explicit Universal Hash Function Family

Tags: algorithm, universal-hashing

In this problem, I was given the follow mapping

```
 U = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} to {0, 1}
```

From this, there is an explicit universal hashing function that must be derived, with the hint that this can be done with a set of 4 functions.  Unfortunately, despite searching through articles on how to do this, I am still confused.  Any help in understanding how to find this hashing function and moving towards the right direction is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

After some deliberation, this is what I came up with; would this be correct?

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
---------------------------
h1 | 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 
h2 | 0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
h3 | 0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
h4 | 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition from Wikipedia:

> A family of functions H = {h: U → [m]} is called a universal family if, ∀ x,y ∈ U,   x ≠ y :     Pr<sub>h∈H</sub>[h(x) = h(y)] ≤ <sup>1</sup>/<sub>m</sub>.

In your case, this means that for any two values *x* and *y* in the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, *at most two* of your four hash functions can map them to the same bit.

Your suggestion:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
---------------------------
h1 | 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 
h2 | 0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
h3 | 0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
h4 | 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

does *not* work, because there are four pairs (*x*, *y*) — namely (0,1), (2,3), (4,5), and (6,7) — where *all four* hash functions map them to the same bit.

Instead, here are some options that *do* work:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
---------------------------
h1 | 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
h2 | 0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1
h3 | 0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
h4 | 0  1  1  0  1  0  0  1

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
---------------------------
h1 | 0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1
h2 | 0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
h3 | 0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1
h4 | 1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I may ask a follow up question: how are the pairs (x, y) decided and how do you determine which space is considered a bit?

Comment: @JoeCur: Re: "how are the pairs (x, y) decided?": All possible pairs. There are 28 such pairs: (0,1) through (0,7), (1,2) through (1,7), (2,3) through (2,7), etc. Re: "how do you determine which space is considered a bit?": I mean "bit" in the computing sense: a binary digit, either 0 or 1. (Usually the output of a hash function is more than just a single bit, but in your case it's not.)